# Godot / GDscript label text not updating every frame like intended

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am very new to Godot and coding in general, so I apologize in advance for any simple mistakes. I am trying to have my text display the variable `ammodisplay` on my object `Marine`. When I launch the game, the text sets to 7 (the correct value) but as I play the game and the variable changes, the text does not update with it. Any insight as to how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
extends Label

var NODE = load("Marine.tscn")
var ammo = NODE.instance()
var ammod = ammo.ammodisplay


func _process(delta):
    text = (str(ammod))
```

Comment: How are you displaying the text?

Answer (score 1):

### Don't copy the value

In the code you are taking a copy of the value `ammo` and store it in the variable `ammod`:

```
extends Label

var NODE = load("Marine.tscn")
var ammo = NODE.instance()
var ammod = ammo.ammodisplay
```

Then you display the copy, which does not get updated.

```
func _process(delta):
    text = (str(ammod))
```

Read the value again instead:

```
func _process(delta):
    text = (str(ammo.ammodisplay))
```

---

### Getting the correct node

Besides, it is unclear from the example if you actually want to instantiate a new instance with this script, or you want to access one you have in the scene tree. For example, your declarations could look like this:

```
extends Label

onready var ammo = $Marine;
```

Which assumes you have a node `Marine` as child of the `Label` in the scene tree. The type of `ammo` will be that of the node `Marine`. The code above is roughly equivalent to (except the version below has worst IDE integration, and worse typing information):

```
extends Label

onready var ammo = get_node("Marine");
```

The type of `ammo` will be `Node`.

In case you are not familiar with `onready`, let me tell you that the code above is roughly equivalent to (except the version below has typing information lost):

```
extends Label

var ammo = null;

func _ready():
    ammo = get_node("Marine");
```

The type of `ammo` will be `Variant`.

It is important to get the node in ready or afterwards because initialization of the node happens before it is added to the scene tree (and thus can't get nodes from it).

---

Chances are that `Marine` should not be a child of the `Label`. For that situation I suggest to export a node path.

By exporting a node path you can specify in the editor when the node you want to access. For example:

```
extends Label

export(NodePath) var ammo_path;
onready var ammo = get_node(ammo_path);
```

Then in the inspector panel you will see a new property "Ammo Path" (Godot auto capitalizes the name) where you can specify where in the scene tree the node you want to access is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to GDscript myself, but I suspect that it should be `self.text = ...`, otherwise you just create a local variable that is not used.

Comment: Those solutions did not work for me unfortunately, but I did find a workaround! Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: And what was that workaround? In case someone runs into the same problem and finds this thread. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you retrieve an new instance of marine, rather than accessing the one you would like to change the value on.

Godot uses scene trees and the `Marine.tscn` should be a child of a another scene.

For example let's say you have a world scene with a textlabel called `Speed` and you want to update the text.

[image: Godot Scene viewer]

Then you would access the speed textlabel in your world scene via `getNode()`

```
get_node("Speed").text = "Speed: %s" % getSpeed()
```